# JMH vs JMeter for benchmarking Java classes?

Tags: java, jmeter, load-testing, microbenchmark, jmh

If I want to benchmark methods in my Java class, which one is a better choice? What are the pros/cons between the two?

Answer (score 8):

I have a lot of experience with both JMeter and JMH. I would say there are many cases where you can use either of them, but in scope of **Java class benchmark testing, only JMH is really relevant**, you can't do class-level benchmarking with JMeter, it will only be a crude approximation. Or it may work if your class is doing some long operations, where precision is not that important. Reasons:

- JMeter's own overhead is significant. For example I have a JMH test that tests function X, and it averages at about 0.01ms. I also use this function in JMeter to set things up in custom Java sampler. That sampler typically shows average of about 20ms. That's 200 times difference, just as JMeter overhead.
- With JMeter you cannot avoid JVM optimization, which [makes benchmark effectively unrealistic](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/architect-benchmarking-2266277.html) (although due to problem #1 it may not matter at all). JMH has a mechanism to prevent this pitfall. I don't think in JMeter you can solve that issue in any clean way.

I also disagree with Dmitri T's notion that it has "Limited number of modes" - *it actually has more relevant modes than JMeter*, and they are easier to setup:

- first of all it has [several modes you can choose from](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/3769055ad883/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_02_BenchmarkModes.java) (including "time to hold the load"). It also has an ability to use all modes at once (with separate results), so you don't have to choose a single mode, and you specify this by annotation or command-line parameter alone. In JMeter it's only possible with additional development (e.g. separate thread group or test).
- JMH doesn't have ramp-up, but it has warmup, which allows to exclude initial executions from the result, thus making sure results are clean from the initial startup noise, which essentially the same goal as ramp-up
- there's definitely ways to control iterations: number, their time, and so on; via annotation, or command line.

Also there's quite a few things that are very easy in JMH , where's in JMeter they require a lot of various workarounds. For example:

- synchronizing iterations is a matter of annotation in JMH, but would require a careful setup in JMeter.
- [asymetric](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/3769055ad883/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_15_Asymmetric.java) test, which allows you to test, for example, producer/consumer model at the same time, but measure them independently. In JMH you write your tests, mark them with annotation and you are done. In JMeter you'd need significant overhead to set it up right

In terms of reporting, JMH, much like JMeter has plugins for Jenkins and TeamCity, which produces result tables and graphs. Also it can publish results in various formats, which can be consumed, processed or stored by other tools.

So if JMH is so great, then **what's JMeter is good for?**

- Mainly for **testing various network protocols**, while JMH was not built for that use case. This is where you probably don't care about JMeter's overhead or JVM optimization, and can take advantage of built-in samplers in JMeter. Nothing prevents you from testing any network protocol with JMH of course (as long as you use a proper library). But in JMeter you are relieved from writing a custom code to handle a communication protocols.
- **You can't/don't want to write Java code**. In JMeter you can express your logic visually, which makes it possible for people who don't code to write the tests (although you still may need to control the logic of the test with some programming concepts, like loops or timers, and you may need some scripting in pre/post processing). Visual recording can also be attractive if you can use it (that is if you record HTTP test).
- You may also feel that JMeter tests are on "functional", while JMH tests are on "unit" test level. But that's quite subjective.

Answer (score 1):

If it's really **your** Java class and all you need is to measure number of operations per unit of time  - go for JMH as it is more lightweight solution which can be integrated directly into your application build system (especially if you use [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/))

- Pros:

  - Simplicity (given you're a Java developer)
  - Small footprint
- Cons:

  - Limited number of modes (workload models) supported
  - Very limited reporting options which doesn't tell much to non-technical person
  - Not many integration options

JMeter is a multiprotocol load testing tool which can be used for assessing certain functions performance as well, there are 2 mechanisms available:

- [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/) language - where you can write arbitrary code
- [JUnit Request](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-junit-jmeter) sampler which detects [JUnit](https://junit.org/) tests in libraries in JMeter Classpath so you can execute them with increased number of threads.
- Pros:

  - Extremely powerful in terms of workload models definition, you can configure threads ramp-up, ramp-down, iterations, time to hold the load, etc.
  - Can be run from command-line, IDE, Ant task, Maven plugin, etc.
  - Test report can be exported as CSV, HTML, charts, [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
- Cons:

  - If you don't have previous JMeter experience you will need to learn another tool
  - Relatively large footprint (at least + ~100 MB of JVM heap) and reporting subsystem can negatively impact your test results, i.e. you will have higher throughput with JMH on the same hardware assuming you use 90% of available OS resources.